# Help wrapping my head around an analysis based on social networks

Tags: regression, networks

I should preface this with a slight disclaimer. The scenario I have outlined is not actually the data I am working with, it is an analogy that I have created (hopefully accounting for all important details) in order to put my project into terms more typical of social network analysis (because my data isnt data that social network analysts are used to dealing with).

Lets say I have gathered information from three types of organizations, non-profits, for-profits, and government agencies (this is essentially a between subjects condition variable). I have 50 of each organization (this is essentially the level of participant). Each organization has three departments: accounting, HR, and projects (this is . Each department can only have 10 people listed as a member of that department, however, members can be cross-listed.

The head of a given agency (participant) was asked to take their list of employees associated with each department and to recreate all the teams their agency has. An employee can be part of more than one team (and therefore affiliated with another employee in the agency more than one time). I then use the info regarding team membership for all the teams to create an undirected weighted network.

The question I want to answer is whether or not employees who are members of the Projects Department in a non-profit are more well connected than employees who are members of the Projects Department in a government agency, for example (see note). This is the bare-minimum question I want to answer, however, I could see it also being valuable to ask more complicated questions but I may save that for another post.

One of the things I am trying to figure out is whether or not I have to account for the statistical dependence between teams (since they are all created by the same "head") and at what stage in my analyses I need to do so. I also am trying to figure out how to handle the fact that employees can be cross listed.

If im in the wrong place, please point me in the right direction. While I am wise enough to know that I dont know enough to do this, I am not wise enough to know what I need to know.

Also, would you say that this is something I would learn to handle in a graduate level network analysis course?

Thanks in advance,
An overly ambitious graduate student who seems to have gotten themself out of their statistical depth

NOTE: so far, the way I attempted to do this was to (1) create the network for each agency. Given that employees were cross-listed, if for company 1, for example, John Smith was listed as both accounting and projects, there is a node for John Smith (accounting) and a node for John Smith (projects) [I am fairly certain this is not appropriate but I dont know how else to handle it]. (2) I then calculated the strength (sum of weighted connections to the node) for each node in the network. (3) I averaged all the accounting strengths, all the HR strengths, and all the projects strengths. (4) I regressed strength of accounting nodes onto agency type.

Comment: I am not aware of an elegant analysis using the network data directly. Your indirect approach, analysing a network index, is what I would do. However, I would use *all* individuals' betweenness score (or whatever), rather than average them, and a hierarchical model (at least with random effects person and organisation) to savour more of the information within organisations.

Comment: Thanks @Carsten, using all of the observations makes sense in a hierarchical model (I assume MLM would work, no? I am learning it for a different project so if it can be two birds with one stone that would be great). Any thoughts on the cross listing of employees that I am dealing with?

Comment: Random effects in a hierarchical models are defined as values drawn from a distribution with hyperparameters. So I think you have two random effects, one is "employee" (random realisations around an employee grand mean with some employee grand variance), and second is department (within each organisation). In the department, you assume each employee to be a random draw around some organisation employee with grand mean and variance. Possibly you need to complicate this, as now any reason why an employee is in one department but not another may confound the effect of department type.